# Running a query and ordering on an avg.

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get all products from my database and order them on their reviews avg rating and not the product name. How would i go about this in my controller?

Tables- **Product**: id, name, price, 
**Reviews**: id,  reviews, ratings, product_id

This is how im showing on my query blade.

```
<p>{{$product->reviews->avg('ratings')}}/ 5</p>
```

Current Controller:

```
$products =Product::orderBy('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Product::with('reviews', function ($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw('AVG(ratings) as ratings_average'))
})->groupBy('id')
  ->orderBy('ratings_average', 'DESC')
   ->get();
```

Try this query and see where it gets you.

Comment: That comes up with a syntax error. and when the failing syntax is removed i get a mb_strpos() error.

$products = Product::with('reviews', function ($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('AVG(ratings) as ratings_average'))->groupBy('id')
                ->orderBy('ratings_average', 'DESC')
                ->get();
        });